# Returning an array of user objects from a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I am calling a MySQL query that returns an array of user IDs. I want to pass this array if IDs to get_users to create an array of users, but I can't seem to get the code right.

My code is currently....

```
// get all users who have done something in the last 20 mins, or just the top 30 if there are more.
$get_user_activity='SELECT user_id FROM wp_wol WHERE last_action_date >= ( NOW( ) -2200 ) ORDER BY last_action_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 30';
$user_list = mysql_query ( $get_user_activity);
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, array( 'include' => $user_list ));
$users = get_users( 'include' => $args );
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have is that `$user_list` is not what you expect it to be.

You treat it like it is an array with user ID's but `mysql_query()` returns `false` or a resource on success.

You need to fetch all your rows first before you can use it in `wp_parse_args()` / `get_users()`.

Something like:

```
$success = mysql_query($get_user_activity);
$user_list = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $user_list[] = $row['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: So something like

 // get all users who have done something in the last 20 mins, or just the top 30 if there are more.


 $get_user_activity='SELECT user_id FROM wp_wol WHERE last_action_date >= ( NOW( ) -2200 ) ORDER BY last_action_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 30';

 $user_list = mysql_query ( $get_user_activity);

 foreach( $user_found as $user_list ) {

  // grab all these values and parse args

  $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array( 'include' => $user_found ));

 }

 $users = get_users( 'include' => $args );

Comment: @user3222828 No, see the example below my answer.

Comment: Sorry, that did not work as when I call $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array( 'include' => $user_list() )); it fails.

Comment: @user3222828 So do `var_dump()`'s of the different variables at the different stages to see what they contain.